# updating a table with a column from another table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a new table from data I extract from the following two tables:

First table:

```
Var     cur_number
-------------------
 A        10
 B         8
```

Second table:

```
Var    new_number
-------------------
 A          2
 A         11
 B          4
 B          6
```

The new table should contain a 'Var' column and a 'Number' column, where for each variable there will be one line with its cur_number, and the rest of the lines will contain the numbers from second table's new_number columns, where the new_number < cur_number.
For example, in the example shown above, for A there will be one line with 10 (its cur_number) and one line with '2' (since 2<10, however 11>10).

in my example the new table will be:

```
Var         Number
 A            10
 A            2
 B            8
 B            4
 B            6
```

The database is very large, and the running time is crucial so I cannot use UNION on the two tables...

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: MY database is SQL server. my main problem is keeping the line with the cur_number

Comment: Please tag more carefully. There is no [tag:data-mining] in this question, and it is not using [tag:bigdata] either, but plain old SQL. I remove these two tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Try this:</strike>

```
SELECT var, cur_number
FROM FirstTable
UNION
SELECT t2.var, t2.new_number
FROM Firsttable t1
INNER JOIN SecondTable t2 ON t2.new_number < t1.cur_number;
```

**Update:** If you are using SQL Server 2008 or above, you can use [**`MERGE`**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to merge the two tables into one like so:

```
MERGE INTO FirstTable AS TGT
USING SecondTable AS SRC
  ON  SRC.new_number >= TGT.cur_number
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (var, cur_number)
  VALUES (SRC.var, SRC.new_number);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1be6/1)

This will merge the two tables values into the first table. The first table will contains:

```
VAR    CUR_NUMBER
A          10
B          8
A          2
B          4
B          6
```

**Note that:** When using `MERGE`:

- You have to terminate the `MERGE` statement with a semicolon, It is mandatory.
- You can't `INSERT` inside `WHEN MATCHED` thats why I used the reverse condition `>=` in the `WHEN NOT MATCHED`.

Answer (score 2):

This script assumes there is only one record per "Var" value in table1.

--insert all from table1

```
insert into newtable (var,number)
select var,cur_number from table1 t1
```

--insert from table2 where new_number < cur_number

```
insert into newtable (var,number)
select t2.var, t2.new_number 
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t1.var = t2.var and t2.new_number < t1.cur_number
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know for a fact that you do not have duplicate values in those 2 tables, then you can use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`

```
select * from table1 t1
UNION ALL
select* from table2 t2
where t2.new_number < t1.cur_number
```

By duplicate values, I mean something like this:

```
table1:

var           cur_number
A                8

table2:

var           new_number
A                8
```

The difference is that `UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION`, due to the fact that `UNION` eliminates duplicates from the resultset by using `SELECT DISTINCT`. In the case you have duplicates, `UNION` is the best in my experience.

Comment: +1 if he cant use union in his case something is wrong in the design

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `Union`? * [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c6f0/13)

```
select * from first
union 
select s.var,s.new_number from second s
join first f
on s.var = f.var
join (
select f.var, max(f.cur_number) maxn
from first f
group by f.var) as t
on t.var = s.var
where s.new_number < t.maxn
order by var asc
;
```

results

```
VAR     CUR_NUMBER
A        10
B        8
A        2
B        4
B        6
```

Comment: This won't elimenate those values of the second table that has `new_number` < `cur_number` of the first table.

Comment: hi I seem to have lots of typos today............sigh please take a look at the updated code :) apology for the first surprise...

Comment: You can either use Mahmoud answer or you can use mine where you remove the `union` and take the results before `union` and inject that into first table. That gives you the expected results as well. Either way one query is qood enough ;)